# Why is Unity 5 rendering geometry seemingly randomly where they don't belong?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering, visual-glitch

Initially I was experiencing weird behaviour with a shader of my own in a project of my own, but it has started to seem that the problem I'm having is more widespread. For some reason I'm having rendering problems that I didn't have in Unity 4. In the Viking Village demo for Unity shaded areas are not properly shown as shaded and some are really dark. And in the Courtyard it goes way worse. Just check the video below to see how just changing angles and positions changes what gets rendered:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S2Bj8FV2LrY

My hardware should be pretty alright as the whole desktop setup is only 1 year old, and I have no problems when trying out some games (although I admittedly haven't played any really new games). And especially regarding the problems seen in the Courtyard demo, even if there was some problem with the graphics drivers, shouldn't the fallback shaders handle it way way way better?

So what could be causing this? And how to fix this frustrating problem?

Comment: It seems like either issue of Normal of your model or Z-Fighting. Well, can you try to convert planes to thicker boxes of which is flickering?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, it does look like Z-Fighting (both in the courtyard and in my own project). But this Courtyard example shown in the video is from the general "Unity essentials" demo, so I'd expect it to have everything working as it is. So it can't be that I just should modify the boxes. The problem has to lay somewhere deeper than that. But where, I really have no clue. It feels like I cannot really do anything about my own project before this more general issue is somehow solved.

Comment: Do you try to disable occlusion culling on camera?

Comment: Thanks for the comment Klamore. But I don't know why that would make a difference? Doesn't that only effect performance? In any case for my own project I haven't set any occlusion settings such as occluders or occludees so afaik that shouldn't have any effect even for performance. In case of the Courtyard demo that project probably should have the setting correct (it is enabled) as it's distributed in the Unity essentials.

Can it be that me having both Unity 4 and Unity 5 installed would somehow cause problems?

Comment: Ok, I tried older Unity versions. It seems that in Unity 5.2.2. (the first version to support the CourtYard project) the courtyard demo works! But in Unity 5.3. it doesn't. Viking Village on the other hand works in both 5.1. and 5.2. but not properly in Unity 5.3.